# XML file handling with node

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

I know my question can be a "noob" one, but I'm kinda lost...

I want to extract "objects" from a XML file in order to manipulate them and add/update them in a database.
I tried to use xml2js, I have a js object, but I don't know how to use it after that...

Sorry for the noobish question.

Regards

Comment: This question is very vague, please get a bit more specific (code examples, etc). There are many ways to achieve this.

Comment: First and foremost, try inspecting the object to figure out how to get to the data you want. Try `console.log(util.inspect(result, false, null))` - taken straight from the readme.md.

Comment: I used this piece of code :

`var fs = require('fs'),
    xml2js = require('xml2js');

var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/foo.xml', function(err, data) {
    parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
        console.dir(result);
        console.log('Done');
    });
});`

I can see nodes but I don't know how to pick one specific node or grabbing the infos inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use [xml-splitter](https://github.com/lindory-project/node-xml-splitter), which may be of some help to you.

It splits XML from an XPath, and return JSON objects...